# How to use AngularJS $templateCache.get()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, caching

I need to cache some HTML files when my Angular controller initializes.

According to Angular [$templateCache documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) I can add HTML templates to Angular with:

```
$templateCache.get('templateId.html')
```

But I can't get this to work. I've tried to get the template file within the controller and within the module run() function ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GxPtYa)). But I can see in the network console that the template is not fetched.

```
app.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.get('templ.html');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I misunderstood the documentation. I thought the get() was "HTTP GET this template URL". But it's just a getter method. To feed the $templateCache with a template with HTTP GET, see the selected answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to fetch html using http request then you can store it in template cache. For example:

```
$http.get('templ.html', {
    cache: $templateCache
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

[Updated plunker code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/E00OhHeccMZ3jcqmy9qh?p=preview)

Comment: Isn't it better to use `$templateRequest` instead of `$http` because it does async template fetching+caching automatically and in Angular-predictable way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $templateRequest to fetch the template.

> The $templateRequest service runs security checks then downloads the provided template using $http and, upon success, stores the contents inside of $templateCache. If the HTTP request fails or the response data of the HTTP request is empty, a $compile error will be thrown (the exception can be thwarted by setting the 2nd parameter of the function to true). Note that the contents of $templateCache are trusted, so the call to $sce.getTrustedUrl(tpl) is omitted when tpl is of type string and $templateCache has the matching entry.

Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest